# Whatsapp on iOS, how to delete voice messages?

Tags: ios

Some of my Whatsapp group chats contain about 100mb of voice messages and I want to get rid of them. However, they are not being displayed as "media".

On Android I could just go to the Whatsapp data folder and delete them from there but I can't access that on iOS.

I've also found the whatsapp support being useless, so I am trying here.

Comment: Swipe from right to left, select more, delete. Does that work for you?

Comment: Hey, it's about deleting ALL of the voice messages in a chat because searching for them would take years in big chats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, after 1000 views on this question it's worth updating my answer:

Recently, a function has been added to Whatsapp that lets you delete ALL voice messages from a chat.

- open Whatsapp
- hit "Settings"
- click "Data and Storage Usage"
- click "Storage Usage"
- select a chat
- click "Manage..."
- remove every checkmark except for "Voice Messages"

(You can also delete other stuff in there but I wanna keep all of that haha)