# How to delete Whatsapp media without deleting messages

Tags: ios, whatsapp.app

The most similar question that I've found is this: [Whatsapp on iOS, how to delete voice messages?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245574/whatsapp-on-ios-how-to-delete-voice-messages) and also has no answer.

I want to keep all chat messages but delete all it's media. I am not talking about the camera roll. I have the setting off, so Whatsapp does not save the media to the camera roll. But it still uses space, so I want to delete it also from Whatsapp.

How can I do this? I don't want to select one by one because there are more than 10k items of media..

Comment: There is no way to do what you're asking without manually selecting each one.

Comment: you could export the app un-pack it and try and find the message store, copy that then re-pack the app, and delete it. Probably an XML file, or maybe JSON, though I doubt it.